# Importing .csv file in MySQL using LOAD DATA

Tags: mysql, csv

[image: SS of my raw data]

You can see my raw data above. I'm trying to import this data on the table I've created on MySQL. Here's the code I should be using:

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'mytbl.txt' INTO TABLE mytbl

-> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'

-> LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';

I can't understand which character is "fields terminated by", which one is "enclosed by" and which one is for "lines terminated by".

Comment: "fields terminated by" - a char/substring which divides one value from another one. "enclosed by" - a char/substring which wraps the value and must be removed during importing. May be optional. "lines terminated by" - a char/substring which divides one line (data for one row) from another one (even when the amount of parsed columns values is less than the amount of columns). See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-field-line-handling

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you're asking for, but you could also just convert the CSV data file to an insert script using Notepad++ and the CSV Lint plug-in https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint/

Comment: Please use text for putting logs or code in your question. it makes your question more readable, and you will find your solution faster

Answer (score 1):

Can you read your .csv file into Excel or LibreOffice Calc (or any spreadsheet program) correctly? I guess you probably can. That means it is formatted correctly.

.csv files contain one line of text for each row of data in a table. These `LOAD INFILE` directives tell MySQL how to find the rows and columns in the .csv file.

`FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','` means each column of data ends with a comma. Notice your first line of data :

```
De Ruijterkade,,123400000001234,,1,105...
```

The first column is the street name. The second is empty, the third is `1`, the fourth `105` et cetera.

`ENCLOSED BY '"'` means columns of data which themselves contain a comma (a field terminator) must be enclosed in `"` characters. For example, if your street name had the value `De Ruijterkade, Kade` your file would contain

```
"De Ruijterkade, Kade",,123400000001234,,1,105...
```

Finally `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` means each line in your file (row in your table) ends with a Windows-style `<return><linefeed>` character pair.

Akina correctly pointed out the documentation.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-field-line-handling